# How to find an ImageView inside a GridView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-gridview

I need to get a specific ImageView inside my GridView. I tried this, but it give a NullPointerException:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) myGridView.getChildAt(1);
imageView.setSomething();
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are doing this in the creation phase (`onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc), but the Views are not drawn until *after* all of these "creation" methods have finished. Sadly there is no callback `onFinishedDraw()`...

However you can put your code in a Runnable:

```
Runnable tweakChild = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) myGridView.getChildAt(1);
        imageView.setSomething();
    }
};
```

And pass this Runnable to your GridView's Handler (inside `onCreate()` for example):

```
myGridView.post(tweakChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply implement the getItem() method in your ImagaViewAdapter. You must be returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the classical way of adjusting those views is via the adapter's getView().

See some explanations here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243248/1665128

[How to find element inside a gridview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976533/how-to-find-element-inside-a-gridview-in-android)

http://androidforums.com/developer-101/146035-get-element-view-gridview.html